# Not able to access C# method from ASPX page

Tags: web-part, ajax

I am trying to access a C# from my ASPX page that is already called from a web part for sharepoint foundation 2010.
I am following instructions from 
[the post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441194/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript)

My breakpoint in the function isn't getting hit when I debug.

.aspx

```
<input type="submit" id="SEND" value="Valider" class="btn btn-success" onclick="ValiderDemande()" runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ValiderDemande() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjouterDemande.aspx/ValiderDemande",
                success: function (msg) {
                window.frameElement.commitPopup();

                },
                error: function (e) {
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

.aspx.cs

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void ValiderDemande() 
    {
        string sssss = string.Empty;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample here ?

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: Where is this page stored "AjouterDemande.aspx"?

Comment: it's the same page

Answer (score 0):

Have you put console log messages your javascript and checked which parts of the javascript are actually executing?

Comment: it give nothing

Comment: In that case, the problem is not on the server side at all. The problem is in your javascript not getting called, so you need to fix your code to actually call the javascript.

Comment: Oh, I see your problem, I think. It appears that you have specified OnClick for a server-side control; that is to call code on the server side. You have code on the client-side, so you want OnClientClick.

Comment: it work but without ajax call

Comment: You would want to put some sort of console log message into that error message handler, right?

Comment: no, i want to acces code behind for my web part page from ajax call

Comment: Yes, I understand. But your error message handler quoted above does not do anything; it does not tell you if an error is happening, or what it might be. Don't you want to see if there is an error happening?

Answer (score 0):

The example you're referring to is for ASP webforms. This won't work for a SharePoint webpart. An option would be to create a mapped layouts folder in your solution where you'd create an application page. Then you'd refer to it like so:
 `url: "../_layouts/15/Project/AjouterDemande.aspx/ValiderDemande"` where the URL would be typically according to the hierarchy in your `Layouts` in your solution / 15 hive.

This is how I had my code behind and JS:

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "../_layouts/15/Project/ApplicationPage1.aspx/GetMessage",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: true,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (msg) {
                     console.log(msg);
                                 }
             })
             return false;
         });
```

CodeBehind:

In ASPX page:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static string GetMessage()
    {
        return WebPart.WebPart1UserControl.GetMessage(); // WebPart is under Project
    }
```

In WebPart:

```
    public static string GetMessage()
    {
        return "Dummy Message";
    }
```

This output "Dummy Message" to the console.

Comment: sorry but i did not understand your solution (create mapped folder, my sharepoint solutio has already a layout folder that i put my aspx file in it )

Comment: Then no need to create that. Just make sure that the reference to your aspx page is with reference to layouts as shown in my answer. Create a method in your ASPX file which calls a method in your webpart. In your webpart method, return the string. What part did you not understand?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a01eb006-c619-49b7-b074-35093b9ab27f/unable-to-call-webmethod-from-ajax-jquery?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious    i have the same issue it call Page_Load() instead of my webmethode function

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a01eb006-c619-49b7-b074-35093b9ab27f/unable-to-call-webmethod-from-ajax-jquery?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

i think that i  must pass parametre to my webmethod